# Are all 3DS NES Virtual Console game multi-player capable?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nes, virtual-console

If I buy a Virtual Console game on the 3DS for the NES, and if that game is 2 player or more will it work? I am not sure if there are any 4 player NES games on the NES... will single copy play work on all of them?

Comment: This is going to vary per game, if it is possible at all.

Comment: even if the game is 2 player or greater?

Comment: @AshleyNunn I believe this is asking more about what is responsible for enabling multiplayer support between the handhelds when the game is already multiplayer—a rewrite of the game, or the emulator/3DS?

Comment: "I am not s ure if there are any 4 player NES games on the NES..." NES supported only 2 controllers; NES also supported some adapters (first the "Satellite" wireless adapter, then a wired version called "Four Score") that enabled 4 controllers.  Guantlet 2 was an example of a 4 player game.  Others are listed on both http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NES_Satellite and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NES_Four_Score   Also, I know that Jeopardy supported 3 simultaneous players (racing to become the person who will answer a question) while using only two controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the nature of the multiplayer. There are basically 2 categories of NES games that I know of:

- Simultaneous play: If the game allows 2 players to play at once, then the game will support Download Play. You would need 2 3DS systems in close proximity to play this way. In this case, only one player needs to have a copy of the game.
- Alternate play: Many NES games support "multiplayer" by allowing one player to play at a time, but tracking progress separately. For these titles, both players will use the same 3DS system.

Some GameGear games also support local multiplayer. You would still need both people to be nearby to play. For these games however, both players will need a copy of the game.

As far as I know, only NES games and GameGear games support multiplayer. Virtual console games for other systems do not support multiplayer in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That is cool that game gears games support multiplayer too. It is a shame that those great GBA games are stuck in single player mode. I plan on buying several GBA games if multiplayer is enabled :)

Comment: @smuggledPancakes unfortunately any other console doesn't have multiplayer support, GBA included. I forget the reasons, but I believe it is because those games are much more complex.

Comment: In fact, on february 2016 will be released the Pokemon R/B/Y for 3DS on the virtual console. And it's already [confirmed by Nintendo](http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-news/classic-pokemon-games-return-on-virtual-console/) that conection will be available for trade and fight.